# How to truncate a String in the middle with ellipsis POSIX compliant?

Tags: string, shell, posix, truncate

In a shell script I would like to truncate an argument when it exceeds a length of 9 to a total length of 9 (first 4 and last 4 characters with an UTF-8 ellipsis in between). It's crucial to me to truncate it in the middle, since the first part is the name, while the last part often includes a number that helps to identify the thing it names.

- `foobarSN9` should turn into `foobarSN9`
- `foobarSN10` should turn into `foob…SN10`

How can this be done POSIX compliant in as little code as possible?

EDIT: I came up with this, but it's not POSIX compliant:

```bash
str="foobarSN10"
strlen=$(echo -n "$str" | wc -m)
delim=$'\u2026'
test $strlen -gt 9 && echo "$str" | sed 's/\(.\{4\}\).*\(.\{4\}\)/\1'$delim'\2/' || echo "$str"
```

Comment: What effort have you made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested in [dash](/questions/tagged/dash)

```bash
trunc() {
    if [ "${#1}" -le 9 ]; then
        echo "$1"
    else
        printf '%s…%s\n' "${1%%"${1#????}"}" "${1##"${1%????}"}"
    fi
}
```

```
$ trunc "hello"
hello
$ trunc "hello world"
hell…orld
```

Comment: Are these expansions really POSIX compliant? Also, can you just put the ellipsis without `\u` notation in a script? This looks super short already. :)

Comment: Yes: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02

Comment: So beautiful, that's why I like asking here. My solution relies on some external tools. Your solution can just be a one liner: `test "${#1}" -gt 9 && printf '%s…%s\n' "${1%%"${1#????}"}" "${1##"${1%????}"}" || echo "$1"`